# MAXIMUM VALUE OF THE LIST

Tags: coq

I have list of natural numbers and its maximum value is not zero. I also have contra statement that value at index nth k l 0 is greater than maximum value.How I can prove that this wrong statement?Because all values present in the list are smaller than maximum value (for all n l ,n<=list max l).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bit intricate. The Search commands in the code show you how to find the required lemmas.

```
Require Import List NArith.
Require Import Lia.

Example listmax: forall (l : list nat) (k : nat),
  nth k l 0 > list_max l ->  False.
Proof.
  intros l k C.
  Search list_max.
  pose proof list_max_le l (list_max l) as H.
  (* discard <- direction in H *)
  destruct H as [H _].
  specialize (H ltac:(lia)).
  Search "Forall" "nth".
  rewrite Forall_nth in H.
  specialize (H k 0).
  Search "_ < _" "dec".
  destruct (PeanoNat.Nat.lt_decidable k (length l)) as [Hlt|Hnlt].
  - lia.
  - Search (nth _ _ ?s = ?s).
    rewrite nth_overflow in C by lia.
    lia.
Qed.
```

As you see you don't even need the premise that the max of your list is larger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to apply contraposition to prove a more "direct" property.

Here is a variant using (finite) tuples instead of lists with `mathcomp`, to give an idea:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma foo n m (l : n.-tuple 'I_m) k : tnth l k > \max_i tnth l i -> false.
Proof.
apply: contraTT => _.
rewrite -leqNgt. 
exact: leq_bigmax.
Qed.
```